# MySQL sumar filas donde ID y ítem sean iguales

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Tengo una tabla que contiene la siguiente estructura y datos:

```
==================
ID item     qty
==================
1  item1     5
1  item2     2
1  item3     3
2  item1     1
2  item2     10
3  item1     5
3  item2     2
3  item2     2
```

El resultado que estoy buscando es el siguiente, se deben de sumar las cantidades de los items que se repiten con el mismo ID.

```
===================
ID item     qty
===================
1  item1     5
1  item2     2
1  item3     3
2  item1     1
2  item2     10
3  item1     5
3  item2     4
```

Esto es lo que he intentado pero suma todos los items que se repiten sin importar que el ID sea diferente.

```
SELECT id, item, SUM(qty) as 'quantity'
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo que pones, estas seguro que ese es el resultado que deseas

Comment: Si, ese es el resultado requerido, esto aplica para pedidos especiales formados por kits, un kit puede contener 8 items, 10 items etc. La cuestión es que el mismo item puede repetirse en distintos kits y el cliente puede solicitar los kits que quiera y en ese caso requiero sumar las cantidades de los items repetidos en el mismo ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **group by** debes hacerlo por los **campos id** e **item**:

```
SELECT id, item, SUM(qty) as 'quantity'
FROM table1
GROUP BY id, item
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: @Sal pq no es necesario?

Comment: Cabe la aclaración: En MySQL < 8 no es necesario ORDER BY cuando corresponde al GROUP BY, ya que ocurre *Ordenamiento Implícito*. En MySQL >= 8 se recomienda *Ordenamiento Explícito*, como en tu respuesta.

Comment: @Sal gracias por la aclaración, aunque realmente el usuario no dice que versión usa de MySQL muy válido tu comentario, yo desconocía eso.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar las cantidades de los ítems que se repiten con el mismo ID en MySQL, puedes agregar el campo "ID" en la cláusula "GROUP BY" para agrupar los datos por ID y ítem. El código sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT id, item, SUM(qty) as 'quantity'
FROM table1
GROUP BY id, item
ORDER BY id
```

De esta manera, se agruparán los datos por ID y ítem, y se sumarán las cantidades de los ítems que se repiten con el mismo ID.
También podrías usar una subconsulta para agrupar primero por ID y luego por ítem, de esta manera:

```
SELECT id, item, SUM(qty) as 'quantity'
FROM (SELECT id, item, SUM(qty) as 'qty'
FROM table1
GROUP BY id, item) as subquery
GROUP BY id, item
ORDER BY id
```

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: La subconsulta es innecesaria, es un paso de mas por gusto, ademas de que agrupas dos veces por los mismos campos, ademas de que no entiendo pq respondes a esta pregunta cuanda ya estaba respondida, que aporte haces tu con tu nueva respuesta si es lo mismo que ya yo habia respondido